# Macbook Pro 2017 15" USB-C display connection issue

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I'm having a horrible experience with my personal Mac (MBP 2017 15") and a USB-C display.

When the USB-C cable is connected to the Mac it starts charging. But doesn't recognize it as an external display at first. I need to plug in and out a gazillion times for it to finally work.

I also have access to a brand-new Apple Silicon M3 Pro  where this doesn't happen (employer-owned).

Some important information:

- If I start my personal Mac in safe mode. It recognizes the display via USB-C cable right away. It's not a hardware issue.
- All 4 USB-C ports are working fine, tested it with an external hard drive.
- No software update is pending.
- The display connects, but it takes forever to get recognized, sometimes more than 20 attempts.
- My previous company computer was a Dell with a USB-C docking station (WD19S), and by connecting the display and the Mac via the docking station I had zero issues with the Mac recognizing a single display. (I considered buying the docking station, but my current setup is with 2 displays, and the docking station doesn't fully support MacOS)
- I tested it with different USB-C cables and it worked fine with the new MPB and it worked with my personal MPB after several attempts. So, it's not a USB-C cable problem.

Any clues on what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you test with another USB-C cable?

Comment: Hi @IconDaemon. Yes I did tried with a different cable and it worked fine. I have this other Mac from the company I work for and the cable isn't the problem. Thanks sending help

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting by with this **workaround**:

```sh
 alias force_connect_display="sudo pmset -b gpuswitch 0"
 alias display_default="sudo pmset -a gpuswitch 2" # This is the default configuration.
 alias connect_help="echo -e 'Utilities to force connect external display over USB-C\n\nforce_connect_display\ndisplay_default'."
```

I aliased these commands on my `.zshrc` and those were the success combination.

When I want to connect my "***vintage***" to my USB-C display I need to force the integrated gpu on battery.

> ***Vintage***: According to Apple, this laptop is old and I have to deal with it myself.
>
> Yeah, this wasn't happening in the past, it only started behaving this way a few updates ago
>
> ¯\*(ツ)*/¯.

---

Explanations: `pmset -b gpuswitch 0`

1. `pmset` is a Power Management Settings on Apple computers
2. `-b` flag to tell in which stage the specific setting will apply.

   - Options are: `-a` ALL, `-b` BATTERY, `-c` CHARGING, `-u` UPS
3. `gpuswitch` The given setting we want to manipulate.
4. `0` on which gpu we are going to work

   - Options are:

     - `0` for the integrated graphics card
     - `1` for the discrete graphics card
     - `2` for automatically switch between discrete and integrated graphics card

References:

- [pmset manual page](https://ss64.com/mac/pmset.html)
- [how to force macbook gpu](https://nathansnelgrove.com/2020/03/how-to-force-your-macbook-pro-to-use-its-discrete-graphics-card-when-its-plugged-in)